# What's the use of "to be" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Sometime I come across "to be" used in the original form itself after a word and don't get its use and what exactly it means.

> The american mouflon from south western Asia is the possible ancestor of the dometicated sheep, which was one of the earliest animal species to be tamed.

Could it mean

> Which was one of the earliest animal species that were due be tamed
> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean **due to be tamed**.

It is an example of [using the infinitive](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/225954) (to be) [with the past participle of a verb](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv331.shtml) (tamed). This is a construction that is often used when the object of the verb (animal species) is more important than the subject (whoever did the taming) or the subject is unknown.

Examples are:

**It was the first star to be seen.**
**Theirs was the second car to be disqualified.**
**She was the only competitor to be timed.**
**He was one of two persons to be arrested.**

In all these examples, we do not know who did the seeing or the disqualifying or the timing or the arresting. So we use this construction to say what happened without knowing who did it or observed it.

We also use it to say who observed or performed the action when the subject is less important than the people/objects affected. We then add: ...seen by the observers / disqualified by the judges, arrested by the police, etc.

In your example, the construction could be changed to **the earliest animal species that was tamed.**